# react js - key vs componentshouldupdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know using **"key"** prop on any React component will re-mounts if there is a change in key value.

Using **"ComponentShouldUpdate"** lifecycle method will just update the component instead of re-render.

In what cases we should use "key" vs "ComponentShouldUpdate"? Does using one provides advantage over other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should revisit the documentation because what you know is not correct.

- a component gets updated when props or state change no matter if you have keys or not in the component
- shouldComponentUpdate gets executed every time before render and tells if the component should be re-rendered or not. for regular components the method just returns true. you can overwrite it. pure components do a shallow check.
- keys only help react know what changed during a render/re-render. they don't stop/prohibit a re-render.

You should use shouldComponentUpdate as a optimization.

Answer (score 0):

**key** and **componentDidUpdate** are used for entirely difference purposes.

From the docs,

> React implements a heuristic O(n) algorithm based on two assumptions:
>
> 1. Two elements of different types will produce different trees.
> 2. The developer can hint at which child elements may be stable across
>    different renders with a key prop.

What this means is that if a key passed to a react component changes, react will tear down the old tree represented by the component at DOM and create a new tree(unmount and then remount the component even if nothing has changed except the key).

On the other hand, `componentDidUpdate` will run after a component has been updated i.e a prop or state for the specific component has changed. Update will not result in the teardown of the tree from the state.

You should not be using key in usual cases and let props/state changes trigger **componendDidUpdate** and handle your logic there. **Key** is used on some occassions where you have a large amount of state logic and you want to reset your state logic to initial state i.e remount your component from scratch. Essentially, you should avoid using key to unmount and remount your component as this operation affects performance.